# How do I change if and else calculation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, conditional-statements, form-fields

My javascript code right now when I choose between value 1(old) or 2(new)

like I choose value 1 which mean old then I put number 5 in chipping table it'll count like this 5*5000 right?

okay so what I want to change from that is

1. Old and New one have requirement old (minimal 80) for new(min 150)
2. Assuming I choose old one right now so the min requirement is 80 right? so when I input number(I'll input 400) in chipping table so it'll calculate 400*5000 but if I input below 80 like 50 only then the calculation is 50*0. So its something like this "(chip < 80) I think".
3. For the new one something like this I think "(chip < 150)"

So the problem is I don't know which one to change in my javascript

Sorry if my explanation not really good I just don't know how to explain it.
I'm still new with javascript so I don't really know. Once again sorry for weird explanation.

```
<script text="javascript">
    function calc() {
        var tes = document.getElementById("beko").value;
        var chip = document.getElementById('chipping').value;
       if(tes == 1) {
           var result = 5000 * Number(chip);
       }
       else {
           var result = 6000 * Number(chip);
       }

        document.getElementById("result").value = result;


    }
</script>
```

What I have right now is even thought I type 1 in var chip it's still count 1*5000

what I expected is something like this

Beko type have 2 new and old

old = 80

new = 150

so when I input number in chipping

like 300 it'll calculate 300*5000, but if I put like 50 or something below 80 it'll count 50*0 cause didn't reach the requirement where I state the requirement is 80

for the new one requirement is 150 the calculation is same like old one just different with requirement

This is my HTML

```html
<label>Beko Type</label>
     <select name="bekotype" required="required" id="beko">
      <option value="1">Old Beko</option>
      <option value="2">New Beko</option>
    </select>
 
 <label>Chipping</label>
    <input  type="text" name="chipping" id="chipping" maxlength="20" placeholder="old beko need 80 while new one need 150." required="required" onkeyup="calc()">

 <label>Result</label>
   <input  type="text" name="result" maxlength="100" placeholder="Bonus result" required="required" id="result">

    <input type="submit" value="Save">
```

Comment: Your result is only valid in the scope of the if condition, if you want it to be visible to the function then move the var result to the function scope.

Comment: Scopes exist for the reason of limiting life of variables, all variables in JavaScript are objects, if it has a constructor and destructor then these are executed when it comes into scope and leaves scope.

Comment: @SPlatten `var` declarations have function scope. The new ES6 `let` declarations have block scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
function calc() {
  const beko = document.querySelector('#beko').value;
  let chipping = parseInt(document.querySelector('#chipping').value);
  if (chipping) {
    if ((beko === '1' && chipping >= 80) || (beko === '2' && chipping >= 150)) {
      chipping = chipping * 5000;
    } else {
      chipping = 0;
    }

    document.querySelector('#result').value = chipping;
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Jenis Beko</label>
<select name="bekotype" required="required" id="beko" onchange="calc()">
  <option value="1">Old Beko</option>
  <option value="2">New Beko</option>
</select>


<label>Hasil Chipping</label>
<input type="text" name="chipping" id="chipping" maxlength="20" placeholder="old beko need 80 while new one need 150." required="required" onkeyup="calc()">

<label>Bonus dari hasil</label>
<input type="text" name="chipping" maxlength="100" placeholder="Bonus result" required="required" id="result">


<input type="submit" value="Save">
```

Answer (score 0):

First, advice about your html:

- Keep the markup minimal and clean
- Try to put as much of the styling and javascript in external files (or at least outside of the document body.
- If an input expects number-only values, use a `type=number` input -- these even have `min` and `max` attributes if you want to go down that path.
- The calculate result field mustn't be modified by the user, so you can logically make it `readonly`.
- Unless you have a reason to use `id` attributes (like for styling), omit them because your form submission will be ignoring them.
- You may want to review your `maxlength` values.

Here's what I'm thinking...

```
<form name="yourForm">
  <label>Beko Type</label>
  <select name="bekotype">
      <option value=1>Old Beko</option>
      <option value=2>New Beko</option>
  </select>

  <label>Chipping</label>
  <input type="number" name="chipping" maxlength="20" required>


  <label>Result</label>
  <input type="number" name="result" maxlength="100" required placeholder="bonus" readonly>

  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

About the javascript:

- When you need to use anything more than once, declare it as something.  Very generally, if it will never change, make it `const`; if it may change, use `let`.
- I almost always use jQuery for the ease of scripting, but javascript can do the same job.  I am going to declare event listeners with `addEventListener()`, but there are a couple different ways to go about it.
- I am writing the minimum values for `chipping` in the javascript as a lookup array/object.  This means I don't have to bake it into the html.  Writing all of the data and processing in the javascript means you'll never have to comb through the html when making amendments.  If you don't actually want to submit `1` and `2`, you can omit the value attributes and use `Old Beko` and `New Beko` in the lookup array/object.
- When the entered `chipping` value is below the minimum, my custom function will be returning and empty string. This is done so that the form submission will fail (due to the `required` attribute in `result`.
- A `keyup` event is okay, but it will fire every time a user presses a key (even if that key doesn't modify the input value).  Also, if a user uses mouseclicks to copy-paste a value, the event won't fire.  I prefer to use `input` as the trigger so that the custom function is only executed if the input value is modified.
- I am deliberately update the `minFactor` and the chipping `placeholder` onload and on bekotype change so that they are always correct.

Here's my take on the js:

```
function updateChipping() {
    minFactor = optionMinimums[beko.options[beko.selectedIndex].value];
    chipping.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Minimum value: ' + minFactor);
}

function calculateResult() {
    const chip = Number(chipping.value);
    result.value = chip >= minFactor ? chip * 5000 : '';
}

const form = document.yourForm,
      chipping = form.chipping,
      beko = form.bekotype,
      result = form.result,
      optionMinimums = {1:80, 2:150};

let minFactor;

updateChipping();
beko.addEventListener("change", updateChipping);
chipping.addEventListener("input", calculateResult);
```

and here is [the jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dxabp6s4/).